# scrypt support in Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, scrypt

Could someone please point out an scrypt bundle for Symfony2 available which could be used?
I could not find much information on scrypt (or even bcrypt for Symfony2), and from what I can gather, there is not a PHP version available for scrypt.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just released a bundle that provides a Symfony2 scrypt password encoder, it's [on github](https://github.com/andreausu/UsuScryptPasswordEncoderBundle).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about scrypt, but if you need a bcrypt password encoder for Symfony2 projects, you can use [my bundle](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderBundle).

Comment: thanks... i actually had your github repo open for some time now, but was waiting for some scrypt bundle... all the roads were leading to ur repo only...

guess i'm left with no other option... ;)